# Ubuntu 22.04.3 Bluetooth error, active in systemctl but in GUI when ON still does not display anything

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth

I use dual boot with Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04. In the GUI, Ubuntu does not detect anything like on image, but in `systemctl status bluetooth` it's active.

[image: Active Bluetooth]

When booting there is an error like this.

```
bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c77 failed: -56
```

I tried to reinstall it, but it didn't change anything.